# NodeJS Redis-Sessions "cb is not a function"

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use Redis-Sessions module to create and store session data.  It works when I'm using web sockets for communication, but I just tried to get it to work on server side page load to check whether the user is logged in or not.  I get this weird error:

```
TypeError: cb is not a function at RedisSessions._handleError             (node_modules/redis-sessions/index.js:452:7) at RedisSessions._handleError     (node_modules/redis-sessions/index.js:19:61) at RedisSessions._validate     (node_modules/redis-sessions/index.js:554:20) at RedisSessions.get     (node_modules/redis-sessions/index.js:140:22) at RedisSessions.get     (node_modules/redis-sessions/index.js:19:61) at     Object.module.exports.getHomepage (server/pages.js:29:39) at next (native)
  at Object.dispatch (node_modules/koa-router/lib/router.js:331:14)
  at next (native)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/koa/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:12)
```

The code looks similar to:

```
var RedisSessions = require("redis-sessions");
var rs = new RedisSessions();

module.exports = {
getHomepage: function*()
{
    var dataObj = yield initialiseSite();
    var sessionCookie = this.cookies.get('userid');
    console.log('sessionCookie='+sessionCookie);

    if(sessionCookie)
    {
        var sessionObj = yield rs.get({ app: 'appname', token: sessionCookie});
        console.log('sessionObj='+sessionObj)
        if(sessionObj)
            console.log('user is already logged in')
    }
}
}
```

It might be because I am using koajs and yields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know anything about the Redis API but, after a brief glance at the code for [`rs.get()`](https://github.com/smrchy/redis-sessions/blob/master/index.js#L137), it looks like it's expecting a callback. After a deeper dive into their [documentation](https://github.com/smrchy/redis-sessions#get-a-session-for-a-token), the following example is provided:

```
rs.get({ app: 'appname', token: sessionCookie}, function(err, resp) {
   /*
    resp contains the session:

    {  
      "id":"user1001",
      "r": 2,  // The number of reads on this token
      "w": 2,  // The number of writes on this token
      "idle": 21,  // The idle time in seconds.
      "ttl": 7200, // Timeout after 7200 idle time
      "d":
         {
          "foo": "bar",
          "unread_msgs": 12,
          "last_action": "/read/news",
          "birthday": "2013-08-13"
        }
    }
    */
});
```

Assuming `res.get()` works with `yeild`, I believe you'll still need to pass a callback even if it's `noop`.

Comment: Your right.  It doesn't support yields.  Just me getting too used to using yields and putting them in the wrong places.